# Problems when submitting a form in TYPO3 v9.5

Tags: typo3

In TYPO3 versions before v9, when using the native form, I always disabled the cache of that specific "contact" page (where the form was placed). If I didn't disable the cace, the form wouldn't redirect to my "confirmation" (v6/v7) or "redirect" page (v8), but instead it would simply reload the (filled-out) form (on the same page).

So, to bypass this and to make sure that the form actually got submitted and forwarded to the correct confirmation page, I always disabled the cache (Page Properties -> Page -> Behaviour -> Disable cache).

In TYPO3 v9 however, this option has been removed, and adding config.no_cache = 1 into that specific page (in a TS template), doesn't seem to do the (same) trick.

I would expect that the form, after clicking the submit button, would forward to the confirmation (redirect) page which I configured insde the form itself. That confirmation page isn't usergroup-protected or anything, it's simply a sub-page of the "contact" page (containing the form) itself.

Comment: You should explain more clearly what exactly you did (how does your form definition look like, etc.), what you expected and especially what happens instead.

Comment: The form definition in TYPO3 v9 (as well as in v8) isn't visible like it was prior to v8 (v4-v7), as far as I know. The issue happens with every form setup where I choose Form action "redirect". Even when I just add a name field, when clicking submit the form won't actually submit and redirect to the page I configured it to redirect to, but instead will just reload the (filled out) form. It doesn't show any (form) errors either; nor does the TYPO3 log indicate anything is wrong.

Comment: How exactly do you fill the field? Completely manually by typing or automated using autofill or a form filler extension? The latter two can accidentally fill the honeypot field and prevent the form from being submitted. In this situation you should be able to submit the form by sending it twice.

Comment: That's interesting. I do use Google Chrome's auto-form-fill feature, and the form does in fact get send after the second try (after hitting the submit button another time). Wow! Is there any way to prevent this from happening? I mean, so many people user Chrome, right? Thanks again!

Comment: You can comment/vote on this issue: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=132135

Comment: I've added a proper answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mathias Brodola righfully points out, this seems to be a problem in Chrome only. I found this following plugin - that completely disables autocomplete support for a form - to be helpful in this matter. It solved my issue (however, it does completely disable auto-complete support for the form): 
https://github.com/terrylinooo/jquery.disableAutoFill

Answer (score 2):

The actual issue in this case is that you are most likely using some kind of autofill for your fields, e.g. from Chrome or using a form filler extension.

This will also fill the honeypot field of your form which then prevents submitting the form.

Right now there is nothing you can do about this except voting for the [bug in the Chromium issue tracker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=132135).